# Set an auto zoom/center base on markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 5 markers in my Google Maps. All of them located inside the US.

[image]

I want to zoom in and center base on all my markers.

Here is what I have now

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {


    var data = $locations;
    var locations = [];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      locations[i] = [];
      locations[i][0] = data[i]['name'];
      locations[i][1] = data[i]['lat'];
      locations[i][2] = data[i]['lng'];
      locations[i][3] = i;
    }



    console.log(JSON.stringify(locations))

    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      bounds.extend(marker.position);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
      map.setZoom(3);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
  }

  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;


</script>
```

---

## My goal

is to get this

[image]

Comment: Is it not working?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [The posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/548paerr/).

Comment: @geocodezip : I'm not saying that it is not working. It is working but I'm trying to center/zoom it.

Comment: What do you mean by that ("I'm trying to center/zoom it")? Your call to `map.fitBounds(bounds)` centers the map on the data.  Sounds like it isn't doing what you want.  Please specify what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: My 2 farest markers are in CA, and MA. I want to show just that area that I annotate in red box in my post. I don't want to show other countries if my markers is not there. I'm not even sure if Google Map API offer something like that.

Comment: Zoom levels are integer numbers.  fitBounds zooms the map for the best fit (although there is a small amount of padding around the edges).  The best result will depend on the HTML viewport's size and shape, which you haven't specified in your question.

Comment: When I saw your comment about `map.setZoom()`, I've tried comment out this line of my original code `// var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
    //     map.setZoom(3);
    //     google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    // });` It works.

Comment: @geocodezip : You're answering my question. You may want to add, so I can accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to [`map.fitBounds(bounds)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) centers the map on the data.
Zoom levels are integer numbers. `fitBounds` zooms the map for the best fit (although there is a small amount of padding around the edges). The best result will depend on the HTML viewport's size and shape, which you haven't specified in your question.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

> fitBounds(bounds:LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral) | 
>   Return Value:  None
>
> Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var data = $locations;
  var locations = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    locations[i] = [];
    locations[i][0] = data[i]['name'];
    locations[i][1] = data[i]['lat'];
    locations[i][2] = data[i]['lng'];
    locations[i][3] = i;
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(locations))
  window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: bounds,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red'
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
var $locations = [{
  name: "New York, NY",
  lat: 40.7127837,
  lng: -74.0059413
}, {
  name: "Boston, MA",
  lat: 42.3600825,
  lng: -71.05888
}, {
  name: "San Francisco",
  lat: 37.7749295,
  lng: -122.4194155
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`map.fitBounds` will automatically zoom the map for you, don't use `map.setZoom` since it will override it.

> **fitBounds**: Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds

```js
function initialize() {

  var data = [{
    name: 'Recoleta',
    lat: -34.585287,
    lng: -58.397765
  }, {
    name: 'Palermo',
    lat: -34.587117,
    lng: -58.421475
  }, {
    name: 'Belgrano',
    lat: -34.562704,
    lng: -58.454754
  }];
  
  //locations wasn't needed, since data had all the info already.

  window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    maxZoom: 15 //In case you only have one marker.
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng),
      map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(data[i].name);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
      //map.setZoom(3); Remove this
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
  });

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

```css
#map { width: 300px; height: 180px; }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

You should probably set `maxZoom` property to the map, in case you only have one marker, because `fitBounds` zoom won't be pretty.

```
window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    maxZoom: 15 //In case you only have one marker.
});
```

Comment: The posted code uses map.fitBounds and works as posted.

Comment: @geocodezip Weird, I tested it, and didn't worked for me, but I'm seeing your fiddle.

Comment: @geocodezip It's because of the markers, my markers are closer together. Use his code, with my markers, and you will see, it's because of setZoom after fitBounds.